# jquery update, undefined local variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I would like to update a vote count by javascript.

My show action:

```
 <%= render :partial => @car.reviews %>
```

The review partial has:

```
 <p id="review_<%= review.id%>"><%= pluralize(review.votes_count, 'vote') %>
```

votes/create.js.erb

```
  $("review_<%= review.id %>").html("<%= pluralize(review.votes_count, 'vote') %>");
```

The vote gets posted without any problem.  But the javascript does not work, ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `review'

Comment: I am wondering if review in the partial were an instance variable could I then use it in the votes/create.js/erb file?  Is it possible to access @review in the partial file?

Comment: The partial file will have access to any instance variables in the create/update action (aka the action you post to)

Comment: This is what is happening in the partial: <% @car.reviews.each do |review| %>.  I included that loop in the create.js.erb with an alert message and it shows all the values including the correct new value.  But the actual HTML doesn't get changed. -- The undefined local variable error happened when I did not have the loop.

Comment: In the js for create.js.erb your selector is wrong. it should be $("#review_<%= review.id %>")

Comment: Yes!  That was part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is to include the loop in the .js.erb file.

```
<% @car.reviews.each do |review| %>
 $("#review_<%= review.id %>").html("<%= pluralize(review.votes_count, 'vote') %>");
<% end %>
```